# What's Easer a Tab or a Navigation Application using MVVM - WPF - C#.NET

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I need to develop a simple application which will contain 5 different pages/windows and I'm debating whether to do it as a Tab or a Navigation application. The reason I'm not sure is because I would like to use the MVVM pattern.

What would be the easiest or best approach to create an app like the one shown in the picture below following the MVVM pattern, tab or navigation?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Without doubt, Tabs. You will face all kinds of problems in passing data from Page to Page. And it is a altogether diff field of WPF.

Comment: you can use `TabControl` and `Frame`. Simply navigate the `Pages` in frames. MVVM will be fine

Comment: Depends on use case, but tab navigation may be easier w/o a framework. Tab navigation isn't very modern these days and tabbed applications are usually a pain to use (bad user experience).Question is: What are your business requirements? This should decide which one to use, not which is "easier to implement and use". @AnjumSKhan: Can't confirm this, unless you don't use any MVVM Framework. Navigation with prism is pretty easy and straightforward, passing data too and even has a region support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not a WPF guru, my experience is that a tabbed interface is better than a multi-window or multi-page interface in MVVM; you can directly bind your UI elements to your VM properties and do not need any communication infrastructure (e.g. a messaging system such as the one in MVVMLight).

Comment: I looks like a Tab-App is the way to go. I will try to find information about tab-application with MVVM. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @fs_tigre: Don't make decisions based on easiness, but base it on your business requirements. Who is the app targeted to? End-Users or more technically skilled users like developers? What navigation preference does the targeted user group has etc. Most modern applications are tabless and use one or other kind of ribbon

Comment: I am using the `ContentControl` to display my pages, all of the pages changes are in XAML, not in code behind and no tabs. But that's your decision as I have code behind to display Messages and sometimes use events from  ViewModel when all else fails, but that's just my approach.

Comment: @Tseng End-users are not tech skilled. I actually prefer a more modern looking app but since I'm new to the whole Microsoft ecosystem (C# .NET, binding, MVVM etc.) especially to MVVM I'm looking for something where I can find more information about. Do you know of any good tutorial about app-navigation (tab-less) with MVVM? Thanks a lot.